# How to automatically set the size of a drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, web, greasemonkey, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to write a script in Greasemonkey that will automatically set the size of Drop-down lists (there can be more than one...) on the number of selection options, but with my limited JavaScript knowledge I don't really know how to do this.

Example of subject:

```
<select name="z_pos_id">
<option value="2463">Option A</option>
<option value="2609">Option B</option>
<option value="3013">Option C</option>
</select>

<select name="z_pos_id">
<option value="140">Option AA</option>
<option value="3038">Option AB</option>
<option value="3519">Option AC</option>
<option value="2645">Option AD</option>
</select>
```

Example of desired Output:

```
<select size="3" name="z_pos_id">
<option value="2463">Option A</option>
<option value="2609">Option B</option>
<option value="3013">Option C</option>
</select>

<select size="4" name="z_pos_id">
<option value="140">Option AA</option>
<option value="3038">Option AB</option>
<option value="3519">Option AC</option>
<option value="2645">Option AD</option>
</select>
```

So, `<select name="z_pos_id">`should be replace with this:

```
<select size="*the number of options*" name="z_pos_id">
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete script. It should be fairly self explanatory:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Auto-size select selects.
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

var posIdSelects = document.querySelectorAll ("select[name=z_pos_id]");
for (var J = posIdSelects.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var numOpts  = posIdSelects[J].getElementsByTagName ("option").length;
    posIdSelects[J].setAttribute ("size", numOpts);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a loop with this?

Comment: Yes, but you must precisely define what you mean by "loop".  Are you waiting for AJAX-driven changes?  Open a new question with the exact details.

Comment: Is there a way that I can submit values with doubleclick?

Comment: Probably.  Open a new question for that.  Specify exactly what you mean by "doubleclick", since that's not a normal action on a webpage.  Specify exactly what you want to submit/select/click-on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ln = $("select[name=z_pos_id] option").length ;
    alert(ln); // you can delete this alert after your test
        $("select[name=z_pos_id]").attr('size', ln);
});
```

Comment: No mention of jQuery was made; it may not be applicable to this question.